# I cant click in a button and selenium not finding element selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

[Web page inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IJiH.png)

I want the bot to click on Ya, Benar
I tried this but it didn't work for me:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Ya, Benar')]").click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to user `find_elements_by_xpath`  procede like this:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Ya, Benar')]")
    
for btn in buttons:
    btn.click()
```

it means that `find_elements_by_xpath` returns an array

Answer (score 2):

Be careful you use a method that returns a list of elements.
To click on an element you have to select it and only it

You choose the element in the list for example 0

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Ya, Benar')]")[0].click()
```

Or use the method that returns the first element (w/o s)

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Ya, Benar')]").click()
```